# Expectation of Scalar Function of Multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, statistics, expectation

If $X \sim N(\mu, \Sigma)$ is an $n$-dimensional Gaussian, and $A \in R^n$, so that $X^TA \in R$, and $f(x) = x^2$.

I want to know the solution to the following expectation:

$$
\int_R \int_R \dots\int_R f(Ax)N(x\mid\mu, \Sigma)\, dx = E_X[f(AX)]
$$

noting that $v := AX \sim N(\mu^TA, A^T\Sigma A)$ is a one dimensional Gaussian, it seems intuitive to write this expectation as the second moment of $v$:

$$
E_{v}[v^2] = \text{Var}[v] + E[v]^2 = A^T\Sigma A + (\mu^TA)^2
$$

but I am unsure if this is correct, if someone knows that it is, or has a proof, that would be great.

Comment: One should not use the very same symbol for both the random variable and the bound variable of integration. In the expression $\displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_X(x)\, dx,$ there is a reason why the subscript $X$ is capital and the two lower-case $x$s are in lower case. Without that distinction, one could not understand things like $\Pr(X\le x),$ and one will be substantially confused about other things as well. And the subscript on the expectation operator is also a mistake.

Comment: @MichaelHardy why is the expectation subscript a mistake? I was asking whether the density we are taking the expectation with respect to is the density of the random variable $v$

Comment: One does not take expectations "with respect to" random variables; one takes expectations _of_ random variables. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite straightforward, and you don't even need to assume a gaussian distribution:

$$ E[f(X)]=E[(X^t A)^2]=E[A^t X X^t A] = A^t E[X X^t] A$$

But $$\Sigma = Cov(X)=E[(X-\mu)(X-\mu)^t]=E[X X^t] - \mu \mu^t$$

Then, putting all together:

$$ E[f(X)] = A^t (\Sigma + \mu \mu^t) A = A^t \Sigma A + (\mu^t A )^2$$

Comment: is there a more general result though? this property apparently also holds for $f(x) = \sigma(x)$ (logistic sigmoid). I mean to say that the expectation is taking as a function of $v$ and with respect to the distribution of $v$, even if the function is the sigmoid for example

Comment: I'm not sure what "the property holds for other $f(x)$" means. What about the first term ($A^t \Sigma A$) ?

Comment: I mean to answer it here we explicitly use the fact that $f(x) = x^2$, but I believe this property in which we reduce the expectation from being with respect to a multidimensional distribution down to a univariate distribution holds for other functions, for example the logistic sigmoid. i.e. $E_X[\sigma(AX)]   = E_v[\sigma(v)]$

Comment: $v = X^t A$ is certainly a scalar random variable. So, of course, to compute $E(f(v))$ it's enough to deal with the (univariate) distribution of $v$. But, of course, for arbitrary $f$ one cannot expect to express the result in terms of the first moments of $v$ (and hence the first  moments of $X$).